# ClassCastException error

Tags: java, apache-flex, classcastexception

In the flex app (without BlazeDS), I send an arrayCollection to Java using a webservice.

And I get this error:

ClassCastException:
com.sum.org.apache.xerces.internal.do.ElementNSImp l cannot be cast to MyValueObject

How can I retrive the properties from ElementNSImpl?

Comment: `MyValueObject` class is not a a subclass of `ElementNSImp` that's why it throws `ClassCastException` when you try to cast it. Check where the exception is thrown. Surely, the stack trace contains the line number at which the exception is thorwn.

Answer (score 0):

The error is given when, from flex, I send and arraycollection type MyValueObject, through a webservice, so on Java I have the VO of the same type, and with the same properties (all strings), I receive it as ArrayList and I try to cast.

Then I obtain the class cast exception. I don't know how to retrieve the objects from the arraylist and I don't know why it was converted into an ElementNSImp object.